# Best way to fetch api in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

I want to fetch external api in my project in laravel. what is the best way to fetch api in laravel??

Answer (score 1):

Everything is described in the documentation of Laravel, you can/should use Laravel Http Facade

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

1. Curl for the using external apis in laravel project
2. You can install Guzzle through composer
   composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:~6.0

   composer.json

{
"require": {
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0"
}
}

```
//code is here
```

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->get('https://api.github.com/user', ['auth' =>  ['user', 'pass']]);
echo $res->getStatusCode(); // 200
echo $res->getBody();